# How to use switch() function in R?

Tags: r, switch-statement

The program I want to make gets an integer as an input and the output is the day of the week corresponding to the integer (ex. Input: x <- 3L, Output: Tuesday). I am required to use the switch() function for this, but I always get "Error: unexpected ',' in ". Below is the program I have made. Thank you!

```
x <- 5L
week_num2 <- switch(x,
           1L = "Sunday",
           2L = "Monday",
           3L = "Tuesday",
           4L = "Wednesday",
           5L = "Thursday",
           6L = "Friday",
           7L = "Saturday",
           stop("Invalid input")
)
week_num2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `switch()` statement in R is parsed as a function call.  Since you can't have argument names like `1L`, it requires that the statement be written differently.  You use all values from 1 to 7, so you can just leave off the argument name:

```
week_num2 <- switch(x,
       "Sunday",
       "Monday",
       "Tuesday",
       "Wednesday",
       "Thursday",
       "Friday",
       "Saturday"
)
```

(It would probably be a good idea to include the number as a comment, to make it easier to read.)  This form doesn't support a default value; it will return `NULL` if you don't give it a number in range.

The other way to use it (which I recommend) is to use a character valued expression, e.g.

```
week_num2 <- switch(as.character(x),
       "1" = "Sunday",
       "2" = "Monday",
       "3" = "Tuesday",
       "4" = "Wednesday",
       "5" = "Thursday",
       "6" = "Friday",
       "7" = "Saturday",
       stop("Invalid input")
)
```

In this form, an unnamed argument is used as the default.